# Sorting a map based on multiple values(Java8/Jooq)

Tags: java-8, jooq

We had a data structure that looked something like this:

```
Map<String, Double> responseMap;
```

And were sorting this map in descending order based on value as:

```
responseMap.entrySet().stream()
        .sorted((Map.Entry.<String, Double>comparingByValue().reversed()))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, 
                                      (e1, e2) -> e1, LinkedHashMap::new));
```

Now the data structure of this map changed to something like:

```
Map<String, Tuple2<Double, Integer> responseMap;  //org.jooq.lambda.tuple.Tuple2
```

How can we sort this map on the new value (based on the Double value and Integer) cleanly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should simply change the comparator:

```
responseMap.entrySet().stream()
    .sorted(Comparator.comparing((Map.Entry<String, Tuple2<Double, Integer> e) -> 
                                  e.getValue().v1())
                      .thenComparing(e -> e.getValue().v2())
                      .reversed())
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, 
                                  (e1, e2) -> e1, LinkedHashMap::new));
```

**EDIT** (as per the comments):

Alternatively, you can also use:

```
responseMap.entrySet().stream()
    .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Collections.reverseOrder(Map.Entry.comparingByValue(
            Comparator.comparing(Tuple2::v1).thenComparing(Tuple2::v2)))))
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, 
                                  (e1, e2) -> e1, LinkedHashMap::new));
```

Comment: This won’t work due to the limited type inference. You have to provide explicit types for the first comparator function, i.e. `Comparator.comparing((Map.Entry<String, Tuple2<Double, Integer> e) -> e.getValue().v1()) .thenComparing(e -> e.getValue().v2()) .reversed()`. Alternatively, you may replace the chained method invocations by nested invocations, i.e. `Collections.reverseOrder( Map.Entry.comparingByValue(Comparator.comparing(Tuple2::v1).thenComparing(Tuple2::v2)))`.

Comment: @Holger Thanks, fixed